# Int conversion not working

Tags: python, string, integer

I'm creating a highscore feature for my game but I cant get it to work

here is my method for it:

```
def game_over(self):
    # Game over Screen
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    self.gameover = pygame.image.load('resources/screen/game_over.png')
    screen.blit(self.gameover,(0,0))

    high_filer = open('highscores.txt', 'r')
    highscore = high_filer.read()
    high_filer.close()
    int(highscore)
    int(self.score)
    print highscore + self.score

    if self.score > highscore: 
        high_filew = open('highscores.txt', 'w')
        high_filew.write(str(self.score))
        high_filew.close()

    if (keys[K_RETURN]):
        self.state = 1
```

What it does is reads the most recent highscore from a .txt file and checks if the players score is higher if it is it writes the new highscore into the file

I convert the string from `highscore` into a int by using `int(highscore)` then and on line 10 I do `print highscore + self.score` as a test but I throws an error that says that I can't add a str and an int even though I converted `highscore` to an int and I converted self.score so for some reason one of the conversions didn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`int()` returns an integer, but you discard that result. Reassign it:

```
highscore = int(highscore)
```

The function does *not* change the variable in-place. If `self.score` is a string as well, you'll need to do the same thing for `int(self.score)`, or just remove that line.

Comment: well im dumb i thought that that `int` changed the variable thanks so much martijn !

Comment: It's worth noting that the later line, `print highscore + self.score` will do something very different if those values are integers than it will if they are still strings. I'd suggest using string formatting to lay them out appropriately, rather than concatenation.