# Why is Int() conversion not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Post can be closed. Turns out I messed up something unknown, because now I retried and the `int()` function is working as I wanted.

`

`

This is a small piece of code that I wrote:

```
def damagecalculating(self):
        self.damage = random.randrange(1,100) * self.weapondamage / 5
        self.damage = int(self.damage)
```

(used long words here to make clear what I am doing)

So what I'm doing is calculating the damage a player does in an attack. but I want an integer and not a float so had to add the extra line.

This returns a float for some reason:

```
self.damage = int((random.randrange(1,100) * self.weapondamage) / 5)
```

I don't understand that, because what I see is that `random.randrange(1,100)` is calculated, then `self.wepdamage` is found and thus the formula becomes, for example: `55 * 10 / 5`.

Why would this return a float in the first place (I found it has something to do with the `/`)? And why does `int()` not work? because `int(55*10/5)` does return an integer.

I did already find http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/17202363/int-conversion-not-working but this does not answer my question as to why or if this can be done in one line.

Edit:

I don't really see why this would be needed but this is the full code as some requested. Please note that I'm very new to programming and there is probably a bunch of stuff that can be done better. Also it's far from done.

```
import random

class playerstats:
    def usepotion(self):
        heal = random.randrange(100,500)
        self.health = self.health + heal
        self.pots -= 1
        print('The potion healed', str(heal) +'!')
        print(self.name, 'now has', str(self.health), 'health.')

    def minushealth(self, amount):
        self.health = self.health - amount

    def damagecalc(self):                    ### HERE IS THE PROBLEM ###
        self.damage = random.randrange(1,100) * self.wepdamage / 5
        self.damage = int(self.damage)


    name = ''
    health = 0
    weapon = ''
    wepdamage = 5
    damage = 0
    pots = 0


def printdata():
    print(player.name, 'health =', player.health)
    print(player.name, 'potions =', player.pots)
    print()

    print(opp.name, 'health =', opp.health)
    print(opp.name, 'potions =', opp.pots)
    print()

def setgamedata():
    player.name = input('Set player name: ')
    player.health = int(input('Set player health (1000): '))
    player.weapon = input('Set player weapon name: ')
    player.wepdamage = int(input('Set player damage multiplier (5 = normal): '))
    player.pots = int(input('Set number of potions for player: '))

    print()

    opp.name = input('Set opponent name: ')
    opp.health = int(input('Set opponent health (1000): '))
    opp.weapon = input('Set opponent weapon name: ')
    opp.wepdamage = int(input('Set opponent damage multiplier (5 = normal): '))
    opp.pots = int(input('Set number of potions for opponent: '))

    print()

def resetgamedata():
    player.name = input('Player name currently is: ' + player.name + '. Set player name: ')
    player.health = int(input('Player health currently is: ' + str(player.health) + '. Set player health (1000): '))
    player.weapon = input('Player weapon currently is', player.weapon, 'Set player weapon name: ')
    player.wepdamage = int(input('Player damage multiplier currently is: ' + str(player.wepdamage) + '. Set player damage multiplier: '))
    player.pots = int(input('Player currently has ' + str(player.pots) + ' potions. Set player potions: '))

    print()

    opp.name = input('Opponent name currently is: ' + opp.name + '. Set opponent name: ')
    opp.health = int(input('Opponent health currently is: ' + str(opp.health) + '. Set opponent health (1000): '))
    opp.weapon = input('Opponent weapon currently is', opp.weapon, 'Set opponent weapon name: ')
    opp.wepdamage = int(input('Opponent damage multiplier currently is: ' + str(opp.wepdamage) + '. Set opponent damage multiplier: '))
    opp.pots = int(input('Opponent currently has ' + str(opp.pots) + ' potions. Set opponent potions: '))

    print()

def menuoptions():
    print('1. Start new game')
    print('9. Quit')
    print()

def battleoptions():
    print('1. Attack')
    print('2. Use potion')
    print('3. Change stats')
    print('9. Abandon game')
    print()



### ACTUAL GAME CODE STARTS HERE ###

# Set objects
player = playerstats()
opp = playerstats()

print('- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -\n')
print('Welcome to the game!\n\n')
print('Entering main menu\n')


while True:
    menuoptions()

    choice=int(input('Enter number: '))
    print()

    while True:
        if choice == 1:
            setgamedata()

            print('Starting game now!')

            while player.health > 1 and opp.health > 1:
                battleoptions()

                choice = int(input('Enter number: '))
                print()

                # Execute player move
                if choice == 1:
                    printdata()

                elif choice == 2:
                    player.usepotion()

                elif choice == 3:
                    resetgamedata()

                elif choice == 9:
                    print('Quit game')
                    input('Press enter to return to main screen')
                    break

                else:
                    print('No valid choice made')

                # Execute opponent move
                if opp.health < 200:
                    oppmove = 1

                else:
                    oppmove = 0


                if oppmove == 1:
                    opp.usepotion()

                else:
                    print('nothing here')
                    ##### ATTACK PLAYER

            ### SOMETHING HERE WHEN PERSON REACHED < 0 HEALTH


        if choice == 9:
            print('\nQuit?! Okay fine\n')
            print('Your stuff was not saved, good luck with that.\n')
            input('Press enter to close screen')
            import sys
            sys.exit()









input('')
```

Comment: No, `int((random.randrange(1, 100) * self.weapondamage) / 5)` will **never** return a float. Perhaps you mistyped and used `int(random.randrange(1,100) * self.weapondamage) / 5` instead?

Comment: Are you sure you don't modify `self.damage` again after this line or there is no spelling mistake in the name of the variable?

Comment: The `/` division operator always results in a float, in Python 3.

Comment: please add the whole code, your problem is defiantly not `int(self.damage)`, and a useful debugging tip, just use `print self.damage, type(self.damage)` after the int to see if it's float or int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is that in Python 3.x the division operator `/` performs true division - that is, the returned value is float. If you want the behaviour of Python 2.x, that is integer division use the `//` operator. Note, that the `//` division result will be int if the dividend and divisor are integers.

```
>>> 5 / 10
0.5
>>> 5 // 10
0
>>> type(5 // 10)
<class 'int'>
```

For floats, the `//` operator still returns a float:

```
>>> 5.0 // 10
0.0
>>> 5 // 10.0
0.0
```

Comment: Wow, breaking my mind on pages of code and Google searches. And the answer is 'write // in stead of /'. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: @kroolik I can't understand how this solve the issue and why `self.damage = int(self.damage)` doesn't work?

Comment: `self.damage = int(self.damage)` works. The point is that `int((random.randrange(1, 100) * self.weapondamage) / 5)` did not return an integer. So the answer was to write "// 5"

Comment: @LuukV: no, `int((random.randrange(1, 100) * self.weapondamage) / 5)` most definitely **does** return an integer. You did something else wrong; are you 100% certain you were running the code you posted?

Comment: @LuukV `int((random.randrange(1,100) * self.weapondamage) / 5)` is parenthesized well, so it's not the problem.

Comment: Most likely the parentheses were like `int(x) / 5`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I don't really know what happened then. I tried it again and now it's working though I did not change my code... Maybe you guys can figure from the code I put in the top post but I think I messed up something else without noticing. Let's just leave it. `int((random.randrange(1,100) * self.weapondamage) / 5)` works